# Can a smart contract work based on fiat currency?

Tags: cryptocurrency, contracts

Can a smart contract work based on fiat currency? What kind of transactions can be facilitated by smart contracts? are they only open to electronic goods, or can transactions of physical goods also be facilitated by this kind of contract

Comment: What is a "smart contract"?

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer They appear to be [something to do with cryptocurrencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_contract).

Comment: This article has a host of suggested uses for smart contracts:  https://blockgeeks.com/guides/smart-contracts/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a smart contract is just automated enforcement of the parts of an agreement that don't necessarily require a human to facilitate.  So the answer is yes, you can have smart contracts enforce fiat based agreements.

An example of this is the application of a default interest rate if a payment is missed on your credit card.  An automatic transfer from your savings account to your checking account to cover an overdraft is another example.

In 2017 financial institutions use a large amount of automation to maintain and enforce financial agreements with customers.  None of the stuff built in to the hot cryptos is terribly earth shattering no matter how fancy the name sounds.  The difference with crypto is the fact that the enforcement of the contract term(s) would be publicly published to the blockchain rather than just unilaterally enforced by your bank.